# Suspicious file operation : Cannot configure media root and base dir in my django Project folder

Tags: python, django, rest

I am trying to save the project files to media then grap to show in url, so far i have followed some easy techniques to avoid the file operation and stored them in media

my setting.py file->

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

my models.py files model fields->

```
picture = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to = "photos")
resume = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to = "resume")
```

It stores then correctly and shows as media url.

my urls.py file->

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/cand/',include("core.urls"))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

main problem happens when i query a resume pdf file. It can't find the BASE_DIR

```
from django.conf import BASE_DIR
url = serializer.data["resume"]
file_name = url.split("/")[-1]
data=ResumeParser(os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"/media/resume/",file_name)).get_extracted_data()
return Response({**serializer.data, "data": data}, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Although it works when i use absolute path->

```
 url = serializer.data["resume"]
    file_name = url.split("/")[-1]
    data=ResumeParser("/home/riyad/Desktop/kalkedev/services/candidate","media/resume/",file_name).get_extracted_data()
    return Response({**serializer.data, "data": data}, status = status.HTTP_200
```

_OK)

is this is a django issue because i have been dealing with this issur previously and taking the easy way(default base_dir) to store file. Need to find the answer quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually settings.BASE_DIR is something synchronus..you have to write the path like this to make it asynchronus

path = settings.BASE_DIR + "path to file"

then you can add this path to any function, unless directly adding the settings.BASE_DIR will not work.

Answer (score 0):

No not that, i look at it after I posted it and i posted the wrong code where it should be django.conf import settings. The main problem is that it couldn't find the setting.BASE_DIR even if i import it correctly...
It return nothing.

Answer (score -1):

BASE_DIR is in settings, not django.conf

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.BASE_DIR
```

[image]